# Navigate from subreport to parent bookmark

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have created a SSRS main report with a repeater and a bookmarked textbox (item ID) for each repeated item.
For each item, I load a subreport with additional data.

I have created an action in a subreport textbox to navigate to the bookmark defined in the master report.
Unfortunately, it does not move to the bookmark when I click on it.

Is it a supported scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bookmarks do not work for numeric values.

I changed the definition of the bookmark and action to use `=Str(Field!Id.Value)` instead of simply `=Field!Id.Value`

And it worked.